# Angular use innerHTML with escaped element attributes

Tags: angular

Hi I have an html respose from a rest server like this:

```
<h3>Center Align</h3>\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\">This is a paragraph. It is center aligned. Center is, but nature, a fence sitter. A flip flopper. It has a difficult time making up its mind. It wants to pick a side. Really, it does. It has the best intentions, but it tends to complicate matters more than help. The best you can do is try to win it over and hope for the best. I hear center align does take bribes.</p>
```

and when I use **innerHTML** is rendered as:

```
<h3>Center Align</h3>
<p>
This is a paragraph. It is center aligned. Center is, but nature, a fence sitter. A flip flopper. It has a difficult time making up its mind. It wants to pick a side. Really, it does. It has the best intentions, but it tends to complicate matters more than help. The best you can do is try to win it over and hope for the best. I hear center align does take bribes.
</p>
```

Missing the escaped attributes for the `<p>` tag so I have an empty `<p>` instead  of `<p style="text-align: center;">`

Is there any way to render this content with its attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to process your HTML. It's insecure by default.

```
constructor(private s: DomSanitizer) {
  this.text = 'my HTML';
  this.text = s.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.text);
}
```

See the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pg6tx7hn5gaeJik2sCy9?p=preview).